# Why does Scala have very little enthusiasm about it?

Tags: scala

I've noticed over time that Clojure users have nothing but massive enthusiasm for the language. Yet it seems most Scala users don't even really care too much for the language. A few people have told me "It's better than having to use Java.". I'm not sure why Clojure has so much enthusiasm about it yet Scala has hardly any. It ruins any motivation that I have to learn to the language. I don't care all that much for a language to use "Because it's better than having to use Java.". What do you think? I've not known about Scala long enough to measure how much the popularity has increased or decreased over time. What are your thoughts on the language? I'm especially interested in hearing from people who use the language.

Thanks.

EDIT: Obviously this post was more offensive than I intended. I'm not trying to put down either language, nor am I saying that Scala doesn't have people behind it. I'm just saying that over time it seems to me that less people are enthusiastic about Scala as they are with Clojure for instance. I'm not making "Unjustified assumptions" or making a "Dirty move in debate" I'm just asking for theories.

If I had known this would cause so much dispute I wouldn't have even wrote the thread. I apologize for any misunderstandings. I would last like to point out that I **do** like Scala, and Clojure. I'm learning Scala as we speak. Thanks for your posts, the parts with theories at least.

EDIT: September 30th: I do indeed apologize for any animosity I earned towards me. This question has been wildly misunderstood. I love Scala, and think it an amazing language. I was speaking from my own observations, and it appears my own observations were apparently wrong. You're welcome to continue voting this question down, but I would delete it if I was capable of doing so, but I'm not.

Comment: You should put these kind of questions on Quora. Here, people get annoyed quickly.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar quora enforces signing up, which is kinda creepy. I don't like those questions of opinion here either, mostly because of "purity" of SO as a help tool, which should not be discussion tool. But I have to admit I like reading them and answers I get are usually really helpful.

Comment: As both a Lisp user and a Scala user: Lisp is about uncompromising power and flexibility and 'beauty at any cost' and produces diehard adherents (oddly I'm not thrilled with Clojure because of its lack of flexibility vs other lisps or speed vs scala/java/C/etc); Scala is about pragmatism and compromise, as much power as possible that can be implemented efficiently while retaining transparent access to the Java platform - pragmatism doesn't inspire zealotry, also Scala is a bit 'scruffy'.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think there exist users who *are* pretty passionate about Scala. [Daniel Spiewak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9815) writes a lot of [blog articles](http://www.codecommit.com/blog) about the language, and the Twitter people often talk about rewriting portions of their software in Scala. The big reason that Clojure may seem, *in comparison*, to generate more enthusiasm is because, well, Clojure is a dialect of Lisp, and Lispers tend to be very passionate about their language. I think that idea is key: a lot of Clojure programmers use Clojure because they *love* Lisp, not because they *hate* Java, whereas a lot of Scala programmers (not all, but a lot) use Scala not because they *love* object-oriented functional languages, but because they don't want to use Java.

Comment: Why would anyone "hate" Java? It is a wonderful language that powers the world's busiest websites, not to mention Android. Anyone who "hates" a programming language has issues.

Comment: In the nineties, I was forced to take a `COBOL` course in University. I didn't like the language. COBOL was huge in the 80's and to some extent in the 90's. I hated programming in COBOL but loved `Perl` and `C` and shell scripting.  I think liking the language you use is important, and it's not likely you'll love every language in existence, regardless of how popular or important it is. I think that hating a language is OK, and that does not by itself imply that one has issues.

Comment: Some languages have a really high learning curve, and the hair-pulling that ensues at the beginning definitely can warrant hate.  Eventually that hate may transform into tolerance, acceptance, and then love, but it's often a grueling process to get there (my relationship with ML in a nutshell)

Comment: Java is dead, you should replace it with Pony, Erlang and ChefDB as soon as physically possible.  Even if it breaks production.

Comment: @stepanian I hate PHP. I have issues. :D Well I just don't like the inherited bad stuff that will never be fixed because of backward compatibility and I don't like starting every variable with $, but that's all. I realized after a while that thread based architecture is not for me and the event driven architecture is a lot better. I always liked Java mostly because of the high quality libraries and the nice syntax.

Comment: @EricLeschinski Looks like Java is dead since 2010 according to articles found by google. Still somehow it is alive. :o

Answer (score 34):

This is a classic "dirty" move in debate. Assume a premise and then ask a question based on that premise.   "Exactly when did you stop beating your wife?"

The question needs to be edited

```
I'm not sure why Clojure has so much enthusiasm about it yet Scala has hardly any.
[citation needed]
```

I'm not going to question whether Clojure users have enthusiasm.  My experience is that they do.  And rightly so, it's a great language.

But you seem to be casually ignoring the enthusiasm on the Scala side. Brian Goetz says that 100 of the 1300 talks submitted to JavaOne were on Scala.  So that's at least 100 people passionate enough about Scala to stand up in front of strangers and talk about it. http://blogs.oracle.com/briangoetz/entry/how_to_get_your_javaone

Answer (score 17):

I've been programming in scala full time for about a year. I have nothing but massive enthusiasm for it.  Do you ever think that maybe people are enjoying using it too much to spends lots of time on advocacy? At this late date I'd think people would have learned to be more skeptical of hype; the corollary of that lesson is not to assume too much from the lack of it.  (Which is not to say scala has not been hyped, but most of the hype appears to originate with people who don't use it...)

Answer (score 11):

Interesting. Personally, I think Scala is an awesome language (and its strength will show in bigger projects), but you're somehow right in the sense of I don't see comments like "Scala rocks and your language is the suxx0r!!" that seems to be pretty common in other communities.

Maybe

- ... the members of the Scala
  community are more mature? (er...
  older?)
- ... they're too busy writing stuff in
  Scala and they don't have time for
  advocacy?
- ... they already know more than one
  language and know that there's no one
  and only one language to rule them
  all?

(humor implied, no need to start a flamewar)

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty stoked about Scala and as a matter of fact I intend to bet my coding career on it. After being a Java fanboy for so long, my earliest impression was that Scala is merely an academic fad -- a toy language for computer scientists and of little use to serious software developers i.e the astronomer to your astronaut, and I thought to myself then, "C'mon, who needs another Haskell?", but after a second harder look, I was hooked.

This is the language I've been waiting for all my life -- functional, object-oriented, JVM-based, and pretty nifty once you've mastered it. Somebody mentioned showing enthusiasm through writing articles, but Scala enthusiasts should do what coders do best, write code instead.

The more Scala we release -- database engines, application servers, message brokers, build systems, etc, the better. May Scala deliver us from Jevil... um Java.

Answer (score 5):

Scala is not a beginner's language. It's complicated, subtle and requires a significant investment of learning. It's awesome, but it's not easy.

Other answers have made this sound negative:

> **mipadi:**
>   a lot of Scala programmers (not all,
>   but a lot) use Scala not because they
>   love object-oriented functional
>   languages, but because they don't want
>   to use Java

I prefer to see this in a positive light. Scala is a language that has learned from the mistakes of history and strives not to repeat them. It attracts the sort of developers who have enough experience, in Java and other traditional languages, to appreciate this.

A sign of immaturity is the belief that one methodology rules over all others. I know I was guilty, a decade ago, of believing that object orientation was the one true way. Now we have those who claim that functional programming and nothing else is the right way. Scala is more mature than that: it understands that one size doesn't fit all.

Scala is still fairly new (in the scale of these things), and parts of it are settling down as I type this, but it's only a matter of time before somebody uses it to create a killer app, something millions come to rely on. I of course hope that'll be me :)

Comment: I don't really agree that it's not for beginners. If you took 2 groups of people who knew nothing about programming and taught one Java and the other Scala intensively for a week, I would bet the Scala group would be more productive by the end. You can do very complicated things in Scala but that doesn't make it harder to do the simple things - indeed simple tasks in Java are easier in Scala, because it removes so much of the cruft and boilerplate.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Scala because it lets me get my work done faster and better. I don't use it because it's a joy to program (well, it is compared to Java). Basically I think all programming languages suck, I'm choosing the lesser evil.

Maybe Scala is a language that is used by pragmatic people like me. This doesn't mean it's a bad language. This also does not mean, that such pragmatic people would cheer over Clojure. Maybe they just won't use it.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this question after a Google search for the term [scala language popularity](http://www.google.com/search?q=scala+language+popularity). Ironically, four days prior I attended [Scala Days 2011](http://days2011.scala-lang.org/), a conference where hundreds of enthusiastic Scala users from around the world got together to present and discuss the latest developments with this remarkable language.

@Rayne, I don't know what circumstances prompted you to suggest that most Scala users don't care much for the language, but my own experiences run completely to the contrary. Admittedly, most of the Scala users I know, I've met through local users' groups and events like Scala Days and the OSCON [Scala Summit](http://www.oscon.com/oscon2010/public/schedule/detail/15318); this obviously creates a subset self-selected by their willingness to give up free time to learn and/or share their Scala knowledge.

I'm also surprised that anyone who lacked enthusiasm for Scala back in 2009 would have bothered to use it. Scala is still very much an "early adopter" technology even now, and there is (and was) no shortage of compelling alternatives for developers unimpressed by Scala: Clojure, Groovy, JRuby, Ruby, Python... I could go on, but won't. It's not as if corporate IT departments switched to Scala *en masse* and forced their developers to use it: that day is still some ways off in the future. Where exactly did you encounter these unenthusiastic Scala users?

Another possible explanation, I suppose, is that you were measuring Scala users with an unfairly long yardstick. @mipadi's comments about Clojure are spot-on. You'd be hard-pressed to find a more ardent group of language enthusiasts to compare Scala users to.

I realized that you posed this question over 18 months ago. I hope that in the intervening time, you've encountered an ever-increasing number of enthusiastic Scala users, and maybe even become one yourself.

Comment: I'd kill to just be able to wish this question away and never see or hear about it again. Everybody misunderstood it. I guess it's hard to hear anybody mention a language in an even remotely negative light without everybody jumping the gun. When I asked this question, I had been playing around in both the Clojure and the Scala communities. Clojure's community was a wildly different beast. Everybody just seemed to care more about Clojure in the Clojure community than Scala in the Scala community. That's what this question was about, but look where it got me. :\

Comment: @Rayne - no point in wishing the question away just because you're getting flamed. I personally had a similar feeling to you. I was researching which language(s) to learn next, and Scala just didn't seem to have the same enthusiasm that other languages do. Having read some of the answers here, my sense is that I was mistaken, and therefore your question has been useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the questioner is making a somewhat unjustified assumption.  [Programming Language Popularity](http://www.langpop.com/) seems to indicate that neither of these languages--Clojure or Scala has much in the way of support other than two rather ardent communities of early adopters.  If one set or the other of the early adopters is more willing to evangelize their new language they're both pretty small communities regardless.

Comment: It's not about popularity, it's about how people feel about the language. I was just asking for theories. I never meant to put down either language.

Comment: LangPop.com only measures languages that have been added to the statistics, and neither Scala or Closure is popular enough, yet, to justify that.  I'm thinking of adding a category for "up and coming" languages though.

Comment: @Rayne, so if it's not about popularity, what else would you consider to be a reasonable measure of the enthusiasm for a given language?

Comment: Excitement exerted from it's users. There appears to be more than I previously observed.